# Cookie not created

Tags: c#, cookies

Hi there if have the following code:

```
protected void btnAdmLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        DBDataContext dc = new DBDataContext();

        try
        {
            PortalUser login = dc.PortalUsers.Single(q => q.UserName.Equals(txtAdmLoginEmail.Text) && q.Password.Equals(txtAdmLoginPassw.Text));

            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["Cookie"] == null)
            {
                HttpCookie adcookie = new HttpCookie("Cookie");
                adcookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(24);
                adcookie.Value = login.UserName + "-" + 1;
                adcookie.Name = "Cookie";
                HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Add(adcookie);
            }

                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("Overview");

        }
```

What is the wrong part In here? Its not creating anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the cookie to the Response object and not the Request object

```
  HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(adcookie);
```

Comment: You request cookies when trying to read cookies that have been written. So as you do now. Request = the call from the client -> server. Response = server -> client.